# Alan Turing on the philosophy of mathematics

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

What was Alan Turings opinion on the philosophy of mathematics? Was he a platonist? A formalist? If not: what else?

Comment: The question is broad to cover. What I do know, however, is that Turing was not a Platonist.

Comment: Thanks. Did he have the opinion that the continuum problem could be solved by adding new intuitively valid axioms to the standard system of axioms?

Comment: The point you raise is controversial. (Perhaps try to edit the question while adding details? either way - there is a book that might interest you: Computability: Turing, Gödel, Church, and Beyond, 2013 by B. Jack Copeland (Editor), Carl J. Posy (Editor), Oron Shagrir (Editor). (Have not checked it yet myself but it was recommended to me by some professor)

Comment: Turing is generally regarded as holding to a kind of formalism, although that term nowadays refers to a whole family of similar views about the philosophy of mathematics. We do know he attended Wittgenstein's lectures on the foundations of mathematics in 1939 and although they both rejected platonism, they disagreed strongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Alan Turing](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/turing/) for his multiple seminal and groundbreaking contributions to logic and mathematics.

He was not interested into set theory; thus, we do not know about his thinking (if any) concerning e.g. *the continuum problem*; see the list of his math log papers into:

- Alan Turing, [Collected works Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=5G4Eya27gCgC&pg=PR11) (R.O.Gandy & C.E.M.Yates eds - 2001).

Alan Turing works is more relevant for *philosophy of mind*:

> It is also curious that Turing's best-known paper should appear in a journal of philosophy, for it may well be said that Turing, always committed to materialist explanation, was not really a philosopher at all. Turing was a mathematician, and what he had to offer philosophy lay in illuminating its field with what had been discovered in mathematics and physics. In the 1950 paper [‘*Computing machinery and intelligence*’, Mind, 50: 433–460] this was surprisingly cursory, apart from his groundwork on the concept of computability. His emphasis on the sufficiency of the computable to explain the action of the mind was stated more as a hypothesis, even a manifesto, than argued in detail.

---

*Note*:

Why do you think that every "big" logician must have an opinion regarding e.g. the foundations of mathematics, or the philosophy of mathematics?

Comment: I have read that Turing read Gödels paper on the consistency of the continuum hypothesis, so I thought Turing was interested in set theory.